# WHERE IN with Azure DocumentDB (CosmosDB) .Net SDK

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Having seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774379/windows-azure-documentdb-query-where-in-statement) I'm not sure why **the following code for my DocDb instance isn't working**:

```
var userApps = _docs.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Constants.Databases.Applications.ID, Constants.Databases.Applications.Collections.USER_APPS),
        new SqlQuerySpec(@"SELECT r.appId FROM ROOT r WHERE r.userId = @userId", (@"@userId", userId).ToSqlParameters()))
    .ToList()
    .Select(s => (string)s.appId);
var query = _docs.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Constants.Databases.Applications.ID, Constants.Databases.Applications.Collections.APP_DEFINITIONS),
        new SqlQuerySpec(@"SELECT r.id, r.appName FROM ROOT r WHERE r.appId IN (@userApps)", (@"@userApps", userApps.ToArray()).ToSqlParameters()),
        new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
    .AsDocumentQuery();
```

When I execute this, though I *know* the data should be returning me back a result set, it comes back empty every time.

### Troubleshooting so far

#### Variants of `.Select()`

Return strings that I `string.Join` in to a comma-separated list.

Eg:

```
var userApps = string.Join(@",", _docs.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Constants.Databases.Applications.ID, Constants.Databases.Applications.Collections.USER_APPS),
        new SqlQuerySpec(@"SELECT r.appId FROM ROOT r WHERE r.userId = @userId", (@"@userId", userId).ToSqlParameters()))
    .ToList()
    .Select(s => $@"'{s.appId}'");
```

#### Don't encapsulate IN parameter

Removing the () around the parameter spec in the query thinking maybe the SqlParameter spec was doing the array specification?

Eg: `@"SELECT r.id, r.appName FROM ROOT r WHERE r.appId IN @userApps"`)

Ends up throwing "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '@userApps'."

#### Validate via Azure Portal queries

Ran the (expected) SQL that this code should be running.

I get back my expected results without issue (ie: I know there is a result set for these queries as-written).

#### Debugger output for Query 1

AppIds **are** coming back from query 1.

### Unsatisfactory workaround

Change query 2 to **not** be parameterized. Rather, inject the comma-separated list of IDs from query 1 in to it:

```
var userApps = string.Join(@",", _docs.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Constants.Databases.Applications.ID, Constants.Databases.Applications.Collections.USER_APPS),
        new SqlQuerySpec(@"SELECT r.appId FROM ROOT r WHERE r.userId = @userId", (@"@userId", userId).ToSqlParameter()))
    .ToList()
    .Select(s => $@"'{s.appId}'"));
var query = _docs.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Constants.Databases.Applications.ID, Constants.Databases.Applications.Collections.APP_DEFINITIONS),
        new SqlQuerySpec($@"SELECT r.id, r.appName FROM ROOT r WHERE r.appId IN ({userApps})"),
        new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
    .AsDocumentQuery();
```

Works perfectly but I'm not going to accept it as an answer to this problem as it goes against a couple decades-worth of SQL best practices and, frankly, *shouldn't* be a solution.

---

Here's my `ToSqlParameters()` extension method in case it's the culprit (this works everywhere else I've used it, though. Maybe something special is needed for arrays?):

```
public static SqlParameterCollection ToSqlParameters(this (string, object) parmDef) => new SqlParameterCollection(new[] { new SqlParameter(parmDef.Item1, parmDef.Item2) });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you use a parameterized IN list, then it will be considered as a single value when the parameter is expanded.

For instance, for this query:

`SELECT * FROM r WHERE r.item IN (@items) And @items is defined as "['val1', 'val2', 'val3']"` will be interpreted as such:

`SELECT * FROM r WHERE r.item IN (['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])`
which basically means that you're comparing r.item to a single value that is an array of three elements (i.e. equivalent to `r.item = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])`.

To compare to multiple items, you need to use a parameter for each value. Something like this: `SELECT * FROM r WHERE r.item IN (@val1, @val2, @val3])`

A more convenient way to write this query is to use ARRAY_CONTAINS instead and pass the array of items as a single parameter. So the above query will be written like this:

`SELECT * FROM r WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(@items, r.item)`