# Cosmos DB IN Clause thru REST API

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I am unable to formulate search query using `IN` clause for Azure Cosmos document DB

**Query**

```
{
  "query": "SELECT * FROM LOADS l WHERE l.schedulingSystem in (@schedulingSystem)",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "@schedulingSystem",
      "value": "A,B"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried providing values in single quotes `"value": "'A','B'"` as well but 
did not work. I am using `'x-ms-version', '2018-12-31'` header for the query

There is no error response but getting blank response (data do exist for this search criteria).

Any help or pointers are really appreciated.

Comment: You are directly executing on the document explorer or is this in the code?

Comment: I suspect that `IN` isn't supported yet. Have a look at this work around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229108/use-linq-any-inside-a-linq-where-on-cosmosdb/51229956#51229956

Comment: @Sajeetharan In code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a parameterized IN list with [sqlQuerySpec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.sqlqueryspec?view=azure-dotnet), then it will be considered as a single value when the parameter is expanded.

Please use convenient way to write your query is to use [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500720/query-cosmosdb-where-array-contains-items-from-array) instead and pass the list of items as a single parameter. Please adjust your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM LOADS l WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(@schedulingSystem, l.schedulingSystem,false)

 "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "@schedulingSystem",
      "value": "['A','B']"
    }
  ]
```

Similar question for your references:

1.https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/614

2.[WHERE IN with Azure DocumentDB (CosmosDB) .Net SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636971/where-in-with-azure-documentdb-cosmosdb-net-sdk/44639998#44639998)

Comment: had to look it up, so: `false` here means a full match, `true` means a partial match. You can leave it empty and send only the 2 args, it'll be `false` (full match) by default.